# Special characters in Eclipse on an non-US keyboard

Tags: java, php, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

For some reason, Eclipse does not register my keypress and I am not able to insert a pipe `|` anywhere.

I am using Windows 7 64bit, Eclipse Helios for PHP 64bit, Java 1.6.0_24-b05 64bit. The problem is my keyboard layout. The combination for pipe on Slovenian layout is <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

Eclipse has a shortcut bound to the combination. As long as it is bound, it does what the action specifies. After I unbind it, it does nothing instead of inserting a pipe.

It's not working with the virtual keyboard.

It works if I switch to the US layout though where the combo is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>.

Any ideas on how I might be able to get it working with my native layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that AnyEdit plugin added another keyboard shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>. When I removed this one as well, pipe started working with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>.

Comment: You should accept your answer by checking the 'tick' next to it.